# Spring Security: Get OAuth2AccessToken additional information in my controller class

Tags: spring-security

Hi have a situation where I need the additional details I stored with my OAuth2AccessToken to be retrieved in my controller class. I have used

```
accessToken.setAdditionalInformation(additionalInformation);
```

to save the data. How can I get the data I stored in additionalInformation in my controller class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do with HttpServletRequest, by getting the token from the Authorization header and then get the token details from the token store.
The snippet for my code is shared below.

```
public TokenData getTokenData(HttpServletRequest request) throws InputInvalidException {
    String methodName = "getTokenData()";
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.debug(methodName + ", starts");
    TokenData tokenData = null;
    try {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader != null) {
            String tokenValue = authHeader.toLowerCase().replace("bearer", "").trim();
            logger.debug(methodName + ", tokenValue::" + tokenValue);
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            tokenData = (TokenData) accessToken.getAdditionalInformation().get("tokenData");
        }
    } catch (Throwable exception) {
        logger.error(exception);
        throw new InputInvalidException("token invalid");   
    }
    logger.debug(methodName + ", ends" + Constants.DELIMITERS.COMMA + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    return tokenData;
}
```